# How to read file from Visual Studio solution/project?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 FileInfo template = new  FileInfo(@"C:\Users\bryan\Desktop\ReportTemplate.xlsx");
 template.IsReadOnly = false;
```

This is fine for test, but I have the ReportTemplate.xlsx inside of my project solution. How can I use that file instead of a local one on my desktop? How do I reference the file inside the solution?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `Server.MapPath();`

Make sure the file you want has been added to the project: File->Add Existing

```
FileInfo template = new  FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Directory/ReportTemplate.xlsx");
template.IsReadOnly = false;
```

The `~` represents "root" of the project.

I think this will only work with ASP.NET.

Comment: Then Server.MapPath is what you want.  Put the file in the root of the app or whatever directory and Server.MapPath will get it for you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where the file in the solution is located. The home folder is \bin\debug in the project folder which you build. If you want to reference the file which is in the root of you project folder use "..\..\yourfilename.xlsx"

Answer (score 0):

File Properties->Copy to Output Directory

Then you can access it with "ReportTemplate.xlsx"